# how to use PG-SQLite plugin in my phonegap app

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am going to develop an app using html/css and javascript. I know that I can achieve this by using phonegap. But my question is how do I use SQLite database to store record using PG-SQLite plugin. 
I need step by step guide.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at the [PhoneGap Storage Documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#SQLTransaction)?  I mean I don't know how you can get more step by step than that.

*EDIT*
As discussed in the comments, the link I posted is to the WebSQL, not necessarily the SQLite (Which is very similar regardless).

Comment: I think the PG-SQLite plugin is explicitly designed to use a local SQLite file NOT through the web storage api in the browser.

Comment: Ahh yep, that would be my bad.  Either way, there's more than enough information out there that the OP just needs to look for to learn how to use SQLite.  (The [README](https://github.com/davibe/Phonegap-SQLitePlugin) of the plugin was more than enough for me)

Comment: +1 agreed. Other than the difference in connecting to the SQLite (a one-liner), the plugin conforms to the same web storage api in your link to the PhoneGap docs

Comment: Thank you Drew and Ryan. You know there is limitation in use of Websql therefor I want to use PG-SQLite so I don't have limitation for data storage. Anyways thank you I have got what I needed.

Comment: By the way the solution which I needed is here in Readme.md file https://github.com/davibe/Phonegap-SQLitePlugin